# DHCP server doesn't start

Tags: 11.04, server, dhcpd

I installed dhcp3-server in ubuntu server 11.04

```
apt-get install dhcp3-server
```

However, an error message during installation:

```
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour « man-db »...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour « ureadahead »...
Paramétrage de isc-dhcp-server (4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu9.1) ...
Generating /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server...
* Starting ISC DHCP server dhcpd                                           
* check syslog for diagnostics                                   [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
Paramétrage de dhcp3-server (4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu9.1) ...
```

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` says:

```
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: 
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (192.168.1.1).
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: 
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: 
Sep  2 03:29:20 srv dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Sep  2 03:29:23 srv kernel: [ 1625.286737] type=1400 audit(1314930563.298:18)            apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/dhcpd" pid=2045     comm="apparmor_parser"
```

#### when I want access to the file `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` I can not find it but the package `dhcp-server` is installed.

> ```
>   root@srv:/etc/dhcp3#ls -l
>   total 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-09-01 06:42 dhclient-enter-hooks.d
> ```

Comment: does the solution here help you?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/3651/how-can-i-have-dhcp3-server-start-later-in-startup-so-that-i-waits-for-a-bridge-i

Answer (score 2):

Try editing `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` instead.  It should be installed along with the isc-dhcp-server package, and the dhcp3-server package which depends on it.

```
$ dpkg -S dhcpd.conf
isc-dhcp-server: /usr/share/doc/isc-dhcp-server/examples/dhcpd.conf
isc-dhcp-server: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
isc-dhcp-server: /usr/share/man/man5/dhcpd.conf.5.gz
```

Comment: +1, one more thing, dhcp3-server is not a meta-package.. its a place holder. isc-dhcp-server is the actual package that you need installed.

Comment: @SpamapS  -- Thanks -- fixed.  Don't know if the verbiage was different in 11.04, but 11.10 shows it as "transitional" (i.e., a placeholder, as you said).

Comment: thank you **SO** much for this.. it fixed my problem, because I thought it was /etc/dhcpd.conf, **not** /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf.  I was really **really** baffled for a long long time, google didn't help any either. thanks again! +1

Answer (score 2):

To run a DHCP server you need to edit the file `/etc/default/dhcp` first and set the list of active network interfaces. On those interfaces DHCP will serve requests. Then you have to configure the server by editing `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and adding appropriate "subnet" entry.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [follow this guide from the Ubuntu Wiki.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server)